# How can I separate my Flickr non-friend contacts feed from my Flickr friends feed?

Tags: rss, flickr, yahoo-pipes

I can get an RSS feed of my contact's photos via http://www.flickr.com/photos/friends/ , at a URL of the form:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_friends.gne?user_id=<MyUserId>@N00&friends=0&display_all=0&lang=en-us&format=atom
```

And if I change the `friend=0` to `friend=1` then I'll get a feed of my friend's photos only.

However, the contacts feed will contain both friends and non-friends photos, so if I subscribe to both I'll get duplicates.

How can I get a feed that contains only photos from contacts who aren't friends?

I thought I might be able to achieve this using Yahoo Pipes, but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it via Yahoo Pipes.

1. Make two `Fetch Data` Modules. One with `friend=0` and one with `friend=1` Let 'channel.item' be your path
2. Create a `Union` between these two.
3. Apply the `Unique` module and filter
   by `item.title`
4. Slap in a `Filter` that filters for
   repeats using `item.y:repeatcount` then hook it to the Pipe Output

[image]

Comment: I've had this running for a while, but I've found it doesn't work very well - I'm getting lots of friend's photos through in this feed.  I'm guessing this is because the 2 flickr feeds aren't updated in sync.  I think a better approach would be to somehow filter the contacts feed using the list of usernames of my friends, but this will be a bit more tricky I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this will be to use the API call [`getContactsPhotos`](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.photos.getContactsPhotos), and then filter the `isfriend=1` and `isfamily=1` results out.